# ASP.NET Project for an ASHX file

Tags: asp.net, ashx

I am trying to determine what the best project type would be for a project that contains only an ashx file and a config for that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it as a web application project.

Reasoning:

1. For WAP's you don't deploy code to the server.  It's compiled first.
2. It's compiled as part of deployment.  This will catch most of the fat fingered typing errors.
3. (and this is **my** real one): Web Site Projects are a complete pain in the *** for team development.  To the point that even for a stupid simple little app that only I will ever work on I still refuse to click on the New -> Web Site menu option.

There are multiple reasons to dislike "Web Site" projects; and extremely few to bother with them.  So, IMHO, just stick with Web App projects or use an MVC flavor of the month.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose a Web Site Project, let ASP .Net to deal with compilation

Comment: And if runtime compilation performance were an issue, you can always precompile the site.